# Approach to write log to different log files based upon tenant in muti-tenant application using log4j

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

In a multi tenant application I want that separate files should get created for different tenants using log4j. What could be the best possible pattern to do it without cluttering the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "tenant"?

Comment: Are these separate web applications or how are the tenants partitioned?

Comment: @stdunbar its a single web application in which we are handling data of multiple tenants. On backend we have mongodb having different DB for different clients.

Comment: @thatidiotguy basically its single application handling multiple client request having different data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one application for all of yours "tenants", you can use MDC and a MDCSiftingAppender :

```
log4j.appender.sift=org.apache.log4j.sift.MDCSiftingAppender
log4j.appender.sift.key=tenant
log4j.appender.sift.default=default
log4j.appender.sift.appender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sift.appender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %m%n
log4j.appender.sift.appender.file=log/$\\{tenant\\}.log
log4j.appender.sift.appender.append=true
```

and in your code, around a code for a 'tenant' (ideally, a web request filter, or something like that) :

```
MDC.put("tenant", xxx)
...
MDC.remove("tenant")
```

Comment: I think it will do the needful, just need to check code to check if it doesn't mess in case of multithreading. Also at same time it doesn't seems so popular just wondering where multi tenancy did arrived long back, isn't there any standard way to perform same.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update, If used Log4j 2, one option is to use RoutingAppender

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender

In which different log files based upon user can be set into ThreadContext.